# Induced charge and potential on a grounded conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

Suppose we have a grounded conducing sphere *S* and a point charge *q* outside at a given distance.
My objective is to find the induced charge on the sphere.

My attempt is the following: since the sphere is a grounded conductor, the potential is zero in any point inside and on the surface of the sphere. For any point *P* on the surface of the sphere, it holds:

*Vq(P)* + *VS(P)* = 0

or *the sum of the potential given by the Sphere and the point charge is zero*.

I can find *Vq(P)* by integration of electric field. I would then write the sphere potential on the surface using the formula for the potential of a charged conducing sphere:

*VS(P)=Qk/r*

where k is Coulomb's constant.
By solving for Q, I succeed in finding the charge on the sphere.

My question is: from my understanding, the distribution on the sphere is not uniform. Does the equation hold anyway? Why does it?

If the distribution is not constant, then the orthogonal electric field isn't either. Therefore the Work required for moving a charge close to the sphere would change based on the direction I choose, which means that potential is not the same everywhere on the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: from my understanding, the distribution on the sphere
> is not uniform. Does the equation hold anyway? Why does it?

The potential $V_S(P)=Qk/r$ is the one due to a charge $Q$ uniformly distributed on the surface of the sphere. But in this case the charge distribution is not uniform, so you can't use this expression for $V$.

> My objective is to find the induced charge on the sphere.

Hint(s):

1. We know that the charge induced on the sphere resides in its surface, because it is a conductor. Also, the electric field inside the sphere is null. Try then to apply boundary conditions for $\vec{E}$ on the surface, i.e.,
   $$\sigma=\varepsilon_0\hat{r}\cdot\left.\left[\vec{E}_{\rm outside}-\vec{E}_{\rm inside}\right]\right|_{r=R}\tag{1}$$
2. Convince yourself that the problem then reduces to find the potential outside the sphere and derivate it with respect to $r$.
3. To find the potential outside, the safest way to go is to use the [method of images](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node64.html), which relies on [uniqueness theorems](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node62.html). The idea is to put mirror charges strategically, outside the region where we want the solution (we want the potential for $r>R$, so we need to put charges in $r<R$), so as to satisfy the boundary condition $V(r=R)=0$.
4. Suppose that the conducting sphere isn't there, consider only the point charge. Ask yourself, where should I place an image charge $q'$ and what value should it have so that the total potential of both charges
   $$V(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left[\frac{q}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_q|}+\frac{q'}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{q'}|}\right]\tag{2}$$
   vanishes at $r=R$. I can tell you that it will be on the line that goes from the center of the sphere to the charge $q$. Try to find $q'$ as a function of the distances you know and the charge $q$.
5. Finally, make use of the uniqueness theorem. It says that if you find a solution in some region and it satisfies the boundary conditions, then that is the only solution. So the solution given by Eq. $(2)$ is valid outside the sphere, and you can use it to get the induced charge $\sigma$ by means of Eq. $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for precisely stating what I was looking for. It looks to me that this is, all things considered, a "method of images" exercise, while I thought this was a "sphere potential" exercise.

Answer (score 0):

do you know the concept of "mirror charge" then use it. It is true, that the distribution is not uniform, but the different ways  from q to the sphere have different length, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: I am struggling to understand exactly which "different lengths" are you pointing out, thank you

Comment: Are you referring to both Vq(P) and VS(P) not actually being constant everywhere, but only the sum always being zero inside the sphere?